# A way to view your flags

Tags: support, flagging

Is there a way to view whether your flags were accepted or rejected? If not, there should be, with a display similar to [that of suggested edits](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

Comment: On your profile page, there is a number indicating the number of flags you've cast. If you click on it, it will take you to a flag summary. Your information can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/167548)

Comment: @mixedmath See it now, thanks

Comment: @mixedmath Perhaps your comment should be posted as an answer. BTW it is interesting that for many other parts of the profile page we have a link which works for *any user*, for example [like this](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity), but I do not know how to make "universal" link for flagging history.

Comment: Should this question be marked as a duplicate of [Can I see results of my flags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/13236/151595)?