# What determines when and if migration requests are granted?

Tags: support, migration, mathoverflow

I recently requested two questions be migrated to MO. One received a comment after a few days, and then was migrated by the commenter, and the other

([Why is cohomology the direct product of the $H^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1900818/why-is-cohomology-the-direct-product-of-the-hn))

is still here. I've received no notification the request has been denied, and it doesn't seem to have been granted either.

What are the criteria and timeline for if this happens?

Comment: I suppose you read the faq (linked for example [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/migration/info)). From what I read there, it does not seem that your question fulfills any of the reason for automatic rejection. (I thought about [problems with tags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12307), but MO [has algebraic-topology tag](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/algebraic-topology). So I guess only mods can tell you more about this particular instance. (And they are also in a better position to answer your question about migration in general.)

Comment: I hadn't seen the FAQ actually. It is helpful, thank you. The moderator says it is "on topic" here and already has an answer (though the respondent himself calls it more of a "hint" than an answer), both of which are reasons they say not to migrate, so I guess I shouldn't have attempted to migrate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will not receive a notification when your request is denied.

To see whether a decision on your flag was taken already or whether it is still pending you check your flag history (see [A way to view your flags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25006/a-way-to-view-your-flags))

Generally, a request for migration being a flag will be handled by the site's moderators as they see fit and when they have the time to do so.

A common practice in cases of doubt is that a moderator of the source site asks a moderator on the target site about the request.

Another thing that is likely to happen is that some moderators skip the flag to leave it to a moderator whose field of expertise is closer to the question.

To sum it up, either your flag was already handled negatively and you did not notice or the request is still pending as it can take some time to arrive at a decision for the reasons outlined above.

Comment: I see. Request was suggested with the comment that it is "on-topic" here and has an answer here already (along with a criticism of how I phrased the request, to wit, "I would like to see what happens to this question on MO.") The answer I have here begins with "This is not a full answer, but maybe gives a hint to the answer of question 1" and I mean no disrespect to that contributor by agreeing with his statement; is creating a near-duplicate with a link acceptable in such a situation?

Comment: Yes, you could post a new version of the question including what you learned from the answer and linking back to the original.  This is acceptable (regarding etiquette) whether the question is acceptable on MO re content I don't know (it's not my field). But I'd just give it a try.